# custom malloc, segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I'm doing a custom malloc. I did a very simple one but now I'm trying to merge and split blocks in order to improve the efficiency of calls to `sbrk()`. when I try to execute a custom program with not many mallocs it works perfectly. But as soon as I try more mallocs or for example the command `ls` after some successful allocations, it ends giving a weird segmentation fault (core dumped) when calling the split function.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "struct.h"

static p_meta_data first_element = NULL;
static p_meta_data last_element  = NULL;

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

#define ALIGN8(x) (((((x)-1)>>3)<<3)+8)
#define MAGIC     0x87654321

void *malloc(size_t size_bytes);
p_meta_data search_available_space(size_t size_bytes);
p_meta_data request_space(size_t size_bytes);
p_meta_data merge(p_meta_data meta_data1, p_meta_data meta_data2);
void split(p_meta_data meta_data, size_t size_bytes);
void free(void *ptr);
void *calloc(size_t num_bytes, size_t num_blocs);
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size_bytes);

p_meta_data search_available_space(size_t size_bytes) {
    p_meta_data current = first_element; 
    while (current && !(current->available && current->size_bytes >= size_bytes)){
        fprintf(stderr, " %zu libre %d\n", current->size_bytes, current->available);
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "null\n" );
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%zu libre %d\n", current->size_bytes, current->available);
    }
    return current;
}

p_meta_data request_space(size_t size_bytes) {
    if (size_bytes < 122880) {
        size_bytes = 122880;
        fprintf(stderr, "request %zu\n", size_bytes);
    }
    p_meta_data meta_data;

    meta_data = (void *)sbrk(0);
    if (sbrk(SIZE_META_DATA + size_bytes) == (void *)-1)
        return (NULL);

    meta_data->size_bytes = size_bytes;
    meta_data->available = 0;
    meta_data->magic = MAGIC;
    meta_data->next = NULL;
    meta_data->previous = NULL;
    return meta_data;
}

p_meta_data merge(p_meta_data meta_data1, p_meta_data meta_data2) {
    if (!meta_data1 || !meta_data2) {
        return NULL;
    }

    meta_data1->size_bytes = meta_data1->size_bytes + SIZE_META_DATA + meta_data2->size_bytes;
    meta_data1->next = meta_data2->next;
    if (last_element == meta_data2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "gleich\n");
        last_element = meta_data1;
    }
    meta_data2 = NULL;

    return meta_data1;
}

void free(void *ptr) {
    p_meta_data meta_data;

    if (!ptr)
        return;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    meta_data = (p_meta_data)(ptr - SIZE_META_DATA);

    if (meta_data->magic != MAGIC) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR free: value of magic not valid\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    meta_data->available = 1;
    fprintf(stderr, "Free at %x: %zu bytes\n", meta_data, meta_data->size_bytes);

    p_meta_data meta_data_prev, meta_data_next;
    meta_data_prev = meta_data->previous;
    meta_data_next = meta_data->next;

    if (meta_data_prev && meta_data_prev->available) {
        meta_data = merge(meta_data_prev, meta_data);
    }
    if (meta_data_next && meta_data_next->available) {
        meta_data = merge(meta_data, meta_data_next);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void split(p_meta_data meta_data, size_t size_bytes) {
    if (!meta_data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no deberia entrar\n");
        return;
    }
    p_meta_data meta_data2;

    size_t offset = SIZE_META_DATA + size_bytes;

    meta_data2 = (p_meta_data)(meta_data + offset);

    fprintf(stderr, "size of metadata %d", meta_data->size_bytes - size_bytes - SIZE_META_DATA);

    meta_data2->size_bytes = meta_data->size_bytes - size_bytes - SIZE_META_DATA;
    meta_data2->available = 1;
    meta_data2->magic = MAGIC;
    meta_data2->previous = meta_data;
    meta_data2->next = meta_data->next;

    if (meta_data == last_element) {
        last_element = meta_data2;
    }

    meta_data->size_bytes = size_bytes;
    meta_data->next = meta_data2;

    return;
}

void *malloc(size_t size_bytes) {
    void *p, *ptr;
    p_meta_data meta_data;

    if (size_bytes <= 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_bytes = ALIGN8(size_bytes);
    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc %zu bytes\n", size_bytes);

    // Bloquegem perque nomes hi pugui entrar un fil
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    meta_data = search_available_space(size_bytes);

    if (meta_data) { // free block found
        fprintf(stderr, "FREE BLOCK FOUND---------------------------------------------------\n");
        meta_data->available = 0; //reservamos el bloque
    } else {     // no free block found
        meta_data = request_space(size_bytes); //pedimos más espacio del sistema
        if (!meta_data) //si meta_data es NULL (es decir, sbrk ha fallado)
            return (NULL);

        if (last_element) // we add the new block after the last element of the list
            last_element->next = meta_data;
        meta_data->previous = last_element;
        last_element = meta_data;

        if (first_element == NULL) // Is this the first element ?
            first_element = meta_data;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "die differenz %zu\n", meta_data->size_bytes - size_bytes);
    if ((meta_data->size_bytes - size_bytes) > 12288) {
        split(meta_data, size_bytes);
        fprintf(stderr,"call split\n");
    }

    p = (void *)meta_data;

    // Desbloquegem aqui perque altres fils puguin entrar
    // a la funcio
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    // Retornem a l'usuari l'espai que podra fer servir.
    ptr = p + SIZE_META_DATA; //p es puntero al inicio de meta_data, y ptr es el puntero al inicio del bloque de datos en sí (justo después de los metadatos)
    return ptr;
}

void *calloc(size_t num_bytes, size_t num_blocs) {
    size_t mem_to_get = num_bytes * num_blocs;
    void *ptr = malloc(mem_to_get);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return ptr;
    } else {
        memset(ptr, 0, mem_to_get);
        return ptr;
    }
}

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size_bytes) {
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc\n");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return malloc(size_bytes);
    } else {
        p_meta_data inic_bloc = (p_meta_data )(ptr - SIZE_META_DATA);
        if (inic_bloc->size_bytes >= size_bytes) {
            return ptr;
        } else {
            void *new_p = malloc(size_bytes);
            memcpy(new_p, ptr, inic_bloc->size_bytes);
            inic_bloc->available = 1;
            return new_p;
        }
    }
}
```

where struct.h is:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE_META_DATA  sizeof(struct m_meta_data)
typedef struct m_meta_data *p_meta_data;

/* This structure has a size multiple of 8 */

struct m_meta_data {
    size_t  size_bytes;
    int     available;
    int     magic;
    p_meta_data next;
    p_meta_data previous;
};
```

Comment: Since you `#include <stdlib.h>`, Don´t you get at least a compiler warning for redefining malloc(), realloc() and free() etc.?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: the OP would get a warning only if his implementations of these functions have a different prototype.

Comment: @chqrlie So, if they share the same prototype, redefining the functions itself won´t cause any trouble? But how "knows" the compiler/linker then which definition to use - the standard library or the custom one?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: to compile the source code to object form only the declaration is needed, the compiler will generate references to external symbols for the linker to solve. Linking the compiled object modules with the OP's malloc object files and the C library will solve the external references in a defined order: references to `malloc` will be solved first from the object file, then from the library. The behavior is further complicated by the presence of `weak` attributes on some of the symbols and also differs between static linking and dynamic linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some remarks about your code:

- it is confusing for the reader to hide pointers behind typedefs. Why not define `m_meta_data` as a typedef for `struct m_meta_data` and use `m_meta_data *` everywhere?
- are you sure `sbrk()` is properly defined? The cast `(void *)sbrk(0)` seems to indicate otherwise. `sbrk()` is declared in `<unistd.h>` on POSIX systems.
- **BUG** in `split()`, the computation `meta_data2 = (p_meta_data)(meta_data + offset);` is incorrect. It should be:

  ```
  meta_data2 = (p_meta_data)((unsigned char *)meta_data + offset);
  ```
- you should define `strdup()` and `strndup()` as the definitions from the C library might not call your redefined `malloc()`:

  ```
  char *strdup(const char *s) {
      size_t len = strlen(s);
      char *p = malloc(len + 1);
      if (p) {
          memcpy(p, s, len + 1);
      }
      return p;
  }

  char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
      size_t len;
      char *p;

      for (len = 0; len < n && s[n]; len++)
          continue;
      if ((p = malloc(len + 1)) != NULL) {
          memcpy(p, s, len);
          p[len] = '\0';
      }
      return p;
  }
  ```
- blocks allocated with `malloc()` should be aligned on 16-byte boundaries on 64-bit intel systems. As a matter of fact, the `m_meta_data` structure has a size of 32 bytes on 64-bit systems, but 20 bytes on 32-bit systems. You should adjust your `m_meta_data` structure for 32-bit systems.
- you should check for overflow in `size_t mem_to_get = num_bytes * num_blocs;`
- you should not rely on `void *` arithmetics, it is a gcc extension. Write this instead:

  ```
  p_meta_data inic_bloc = (p_meta_data)ptr - 1;
  ```
- in `realloc()`, when extending the size of the block, you just make the original block available but you do not coalesce it with adjacent blocks as you do in `free()`. You might just call `free(ptr)`, especially since modifying `inic_bloc->available = 1;` without getting the lock seems risky.
- you should check `meta_data->available` in `free()` and `realloc()` to detect invalid calls and prevent arena corruption.
- in `malloc()`, you forget to release the lock in case of allocation failure.
- calling `fprintf` while the lock is set is risky: if `fprintf` calls `malloc`, you would get a deadlock. You might assume that printing to `stderr` does not call `malloc()` because `stderr` is unbuffered, but you are taking chances.
- when allocating a new block with `sbrk()`, you should use `sbrk(0)` after the allocation to determine the actual size made available as it may have been rounded up to a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`.
- you should split blocks if `(meta_data->size_bytes - size_bytes) > SIZE_META_DATA`. The current test is far too loose.

Comment: thank you for your thorough pretty much it answered all my doubts!                                                    indeed the pointer void arithmetic is problematic as you pointed, now it pretty much works with all your recommendations. Still doesn't open GUI text editors like kate or gedit thought. Do you know which could be the cause for this?

Comment: in a 64 computer shouldn't I align with 8 bytes? (64/8 = 8 bytes)

Comment: `malloc()` aligns an 16-byte boundaries on 64-bit intel because some vector instructions require such an alignment, otherwise 8-byte alignment would be fine.

Comment: why strdup() and strndup() redefinitons rmake the trick? without them apps like kate or gedit would crash, when I redefine them they actually open!

Comment: @herbert8: As I mentioned in the answer, depending on how `strdup` and `strndup` are implemented in the C library, they might make direct calls to the C library's `malloc()` package or internal routines and not to your redefined symbols, which will cause problems when the pointers get passed to your `free()`. There are other functions you might want to redefine as well: GNU's `malloc_usable_size()`, POSIX `posix_memalign()`, C17 `aligned_alloc()`.